# Why does cout writing out nothing?

Tags: c++, cout

Im a begginer in c++ and i dont know why this code isnt running. *Its writing out nothing... not even the `"a"`*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    vector<string> allat(N), etel(N);

    for(int a=0;a<N;a++) {
        cin >> allat[N];
        cin >> etel[N];
    }

    int meg=0;

    for(int a=0;a<N;a++) {
        for(int b=0;b<N;b++) {
            if(etel[a] == allat[b]) {
                meg++;
            }
        }
    }



    cout << meg << "a";
```

Comment: Stdout is line buffered by default. You need to add a newline.

Comment: How are you running your program? From a terminal? From inside an IDE?

Comment: What does the debugger reveal? Does the execution reach the line?

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And please learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them, like showing us the input you give, the expected and actual (if any) output.

Comment: As a very probably hint about your problem (and which a quick session in a debugger would verify), think about `cin >> allat[N];` Where are you actually writing the input in your vector?

Comment: Discuss `cin >> allat[N];` with your [Rubber Duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Focus on the value of `N`.

Comment: @Qix-MONICAWASMISTREATED "*Stdout is line buffered by default. You need to add a newline*" - except at program exit, when the buffer gets flushed automatically.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is in the following lines:

```
cin >> allat[N];
cin >> etel[N];
```

..as these invoke [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). You should replace `N` with `a`, so the above can be replaced by:

```
cin >> allat[a];
cin >> etel[a];
```

Now your code should work. Also, look up to [why is "using namespace std" considered as a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: That's what I meant. It crashes the program. So I wrote exception. Thanks for informing me that.